# Angular content not working in Kendo Tab Strip

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I am not able to figure out why remove tab is not invoked when I use ng-click but it works fine in non Angular way! I referred help available in http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/tabstrip/how-to/AngularJS/add-new-tabs-dynamically.html.

I have written code in dojo.telerik.com/@datha_k/oNuBI. I'm clueless here, tried a lot, please help.

I think my issue related to this discussion at http://www.telerik.com/forums/use-angularjs-directive-in-tab-content 'The tabstrip widget does not support angularjs binding expressions'. Any work around to suggest?

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/@datha_k/oNuBI

Answer (score 0):

> Hi ,due to some reason i m unable to login in DOJO to edit ur code,below code will work -

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/index">
    <style>
        html {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" ng-app="app-myapp" ng-controller="my-controller as my">
        <button ng-click="newTab($event)">Click to add new tab</button>{{show}}
        <hr />
        <div kendo-tab-strip="tabstrip" id="tabstrip" k-options="tabOptions"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function removeMeNonNg(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            var item = $(e.target).closest(".k-item");
            var tabstrip = $("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip");
            tabstrip.remove(item.index());
            tabstrip.select(0);
        }
        angular.module("app-myapp", ["kendo.directives"])  // Create module and pass kendo dependency
            .controller("my-controller", function ($scope, $timeout) { // Create controller
                var index = 1;
                $scope.tabOptions = {
                    dataTextField: "text",
                    dataContentField: "content",
                    dataSource: [{
                        text: index,
                        content: '<div>Hello World!</div>' + index
                    }]
                }; // tabOptions
                $scope.newTab = function newTab(event) {
                    index++;
                    $scope.tabstrip.append({
                        text: index + '  <button onclick="removeMeNonNg(event)">Remove me in non NG!</button> ',
                        encoded: false,
                        content: '<div><button ng-click="removeTab(\''+index+'\')">Remove me!</button>Hello World, Again!</div>' + index
                    });
                }; // newtab

                $scope.removeTab = function (index) {
                   $scope.tabstrip.remove(index-1);
                };

                $timeout(function () {
                    $("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip").select(0);
                }, 50);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> The problem with your code are 2-
>
> 1)Either use jquery or ANgular for components or else u will face anonymous behaviour.I have corrected your code for appending tabs in angular kendo.
>
> 2)You have to call ng-click from content attribute and not text attribute of kendo-tabstrip

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer and effort. I have to keep button (I'll change them to Icon buttons) in content area , so user can close them. Check http://dojo.telerik.com/@datha_k/oNuBI/2 , i am using two button in 'text' area. Issue I am facing in $scope.removeTab() is never invoked but removeMeNonNg() invoked for 2nd button.